# Bentonite could change the yeast taste?

Tags: fermentation, yeast, cider

hello I am new in this kind of things. I would know if I use Bentonite it could change the taste and smell of yeast in the fermentation ?
I am gonna use breed yeast. I would quickly finish my product and drink

Answer (score 1):

Bentonite clay drops things from suspension. This includes yeast, so only use it when fermentation is finished. It also drops some bigger particles that can contribute to flavors and off flavors. It will not remove anything that is dissolved, so a lot of fermentation products will stay in your drink. This is not necessarily bad, I brewed pretty successful and tasty sahti-like beer using bread yeast.

You are a home brewer. Ingredients are cheap. Best you can do? Ferment as planned, use bentonite on half of your product, and then post your own answer with your results!